# Checking string equality in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script that receives a string from html and checks whether the string equal another string.

I have a problem with some stings. I receive a grade from a to f some grades are recognized and some grades are not.
the problem is with D E and F.
is it possible that the problem from the == operator?
Note: I tried to alert the grade before the second if statement and make sure that I receive a string value so the problem in the following code.
code:

```
if (course1_grade) {
    if (course1_grade == "A") {
        course1_point = 4.0 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "A-") {
        course1_point = 3.67 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "B+") {
        course1_point = 3.33 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "B") {
        course1_point = 3.0 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "B-") {
        course1_point = 2.67 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "C+") {
        course1_point = 2.33 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "C") {
        course1_point = 2.0 * course1_credit;
    } else if ($course1_grade == "C-") {
        course1_point = 1.67 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "D+") {
        course1_point = 1.33 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "D") {
        course1_point = 1.0 * course1_credit;
    } else if (course1_grade == "F") {
        course1_point = 0.0 * course1_credit;
    }
} else {
    course1_point = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: If you can make your question into a code snippet or JSFiddle it might be easier to work out what your problem is. Also consider using a switch case statement instead of several else ifs

Comment: Independently, you should really switch to a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: Test course1_grade.indexOf('D-'). And replace your code with a switch, it will be more readable

Comment: First of all. Why don't you use a switch statement. Second I do not see a condition where you test an E in your code. And your C- has a non declared variable. You can always use a browser debugger to check if your code breaks at some point.

Comment: Strongly recommend stopping what you're doing and spending an hour or two learning basic debugging and debugging tools. Your browser has a fully-featured debugger built into it. Even just looking at the console would have told you what the problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27740870/157247) spotted the error, see his/her answer, which is the correct one. So this is now a comment with code in (hence making it a CW).

For what it's worth, I'd use a lookup map or a `switch`, not a long `if/else` series.

Map:

```
var factor = {
  "A":  4.0,
  "A-": 3.67,
  "B+": 3.33,
  "B":  3.0,
  "B-": 2.67,
  "C+": 2.33,
  "C":  2.0,
  "C-": 1.67,
  "D+": 1.33,
  "D":  1.0,
  "F":  0.0
};
course1_point = (factor[course1_grade.trim().toUpperCase()] || 0.0) * course1_credit;
```

```js
var factor = {
  "A":  4.0,
  "A-": 3.67,
  "B+": 3.33,
  "B":  3.0,
  "B-": 2.67,
  "C+": 2.33,
  "C":  2.0,
  "C-": 1.67,
  "D+": 1.33,
  "D":  1.0,
  "F":  0.0
};
var course1_credit = 100;
function test(course1_grade) {
  var course1_point = (factor[course1_grade.trim().toUpperCase()] || 0.0) * course1_credit;
  snippet.log("grade = " + course1_grade + ", points = " + course1_point);
}
test("a");
test("a-");
test("b+");
test("b");
test("b-");
test("c+");
test("C");
test("C-");
test("D+");
test("D");
test("F");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

`switch`:

```
switch (course1_grade.trim().toUpperCase()) {
  case "A":
    course1_point = 4.0 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "A-":
    course1_point = 3.67 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "B+":
    course1_point = 3.33 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "B":
    course1_point = 3.0 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "B-":
    course1_point = 2.67 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "C+":
    course1_point = 2.33 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "C":
    course1_point = 2.0 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "C-":
    course1_point = 1.67 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "D+":
    course1_point = 1.33 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "D":
    course1_point = 1.0 * course1_credit;
    break;
  case "F":
    course1_point = 0.0 * course1_credit;
    break;
  default:
    course1_point = 0.0;
}
```

```js
var course1_credit = 100;
function test(course1_grade) {
  var course1_point;
  switch (course1_grade.trim().toUpperCase()) {
    case "A":
      course1_point = 4.0 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "A-":
      course1_point = 3.67 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "B+":
      course1_point = 3.33 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "B":
      course1_point = 3.0 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "B-":
      course1_point = 2.67 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "C+":
      course1_point = 2.33 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "C":
      course1_point = 2.0 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "C-":
      course1_point = 1.67 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "D+":
      course1_point = 1.33 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "D":
      course1_point = 1.0 * course1_credit;
      break;
    case "F":
      course1_point = 0.0 * course1_credit;
      break;
    default:
      course1_point = 0.0;
  }

  snippet.log("grade = " + course1_grade + ", points = " + course1_point);
}

test("a");
test("a-");
test("b+");
test("b");
test("b-");
test("c+");
test("C");
test("C-");
test("D+");
test("D");
test("F");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @shahdewai: Then there's *another*, unrelated, problem in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Using an object is a sensible alternative, better than if..else and switch.

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, it's what I'd do in production code. Much more concise, easier to maintain, ... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is breaking when it tries to check for a `C-` grade because the variable `$course1_grade` is undeclared. None of the code after that point runs.

You can fix your code by removing that dollar sign, or you could use a lookup, which would be much more compact:

```
var gradeLookup = {
    "A" : 4,
    "A-": 3.67,
    "B+": 3.33,
    "B" : 3,
    "B-": 2.67,
    "C+": 2.33,
    "C" : 2,
    "C-": 1.67,
    "D+": 1.33,
    "D" : 1
};

course1_grade = (course1_grade || "").trim().toUpperCase();
course1_point = (gradeLookup[course1_grade] || 0) * course1_credit;
```

Another approach you can use is a `switch` statement:

```
function getFactor(grade) {
    switch ((grade || "").trim().toUpperCase()) {
        case "A" : return 4.0;
        case "A-": return 3.67;
        case "B+": return 3.33;
        case "B" : return 3;
        case "B-": return 2.67;
        case "C+": return 2.33;
        case "C" : return 2;
        case "C-": return 1.67;
        case "D+": return 1.33;
        case "D" : return 1;
        default  : return 0;
    }
}

course1_point = getFactor(course1_grade) * course1_credit;
```

Comment: Recommend adding trimming and capping, and you can use the `||` operator to make things less verbose. Feel free to grab anything from my CW that would be useful; if incorporated here, I can delete it.

Comment: @RobG Please carefully read my answer again. The undeclared variable is ___$course1_grade___.

Comment: @RobG: Not `course1_grade`, `$course1_grade`. Since the `ReferenceError` won't occur unless code execution reaches the line with the errant `$`, it only happens as of `C-` as JL said.

Comment: But the OP doesn't say there's an error, perhaps not looking at the console.

Comment: @RobG OP wouldn't recognize an error if it hit him on the nose, but he says that the code doesn't work for `D`, `E` and `F`. His code also has an undeclared variable in it right before the check for `D` and `F`.

Comment: @JLRishe—there are no declared variables in the OP.

Comment: @RobG: It's fairly clear that the poster doesn't know anything about fundamental debugging on browsers. And sure, there are no declarations in the code in the question, but given the symptom described, it's entirely reasonable to assume that `course1_grade` **is** declared and that `$course1_grade`, an obvious typo, is not.

Comment: @RobG What's your point? Do you think that there's some valid reason why the `if` statement for `C-` is using a different variable from all the others?